# Why does my Greninja get boosted EXP?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

For the last couple of battles, I've noticed that my Greninja receives boosted EXP despite never having been traded. He has also been moving from side to side at the start of battle since around the same time I noticed the EXP increase.

I've been to Pokémon Centres multiple times since noticing and it doesn't seem to be Pokérus (although I click through the nurse's dialogue quickly, so I may have missed it if it's not displayed elsewhere)

What could be affecting my Greninja?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While evolving a Sylveon for a trade, I stumbled upon a solution. Once I was ready to level up my Eevee, I noticed that he too was receiving boosted EXP. As it turns out, I had messed around Pokémon-Amie with Greninja and he ended up with 2 hearts of enjoyment. To verify this hypothesis, I played with a spare Gabite, defeating a wild pokémon after each additional heart.

With a single heart, there was no noticeable change to the Gabite: she still earned normal EXP and didn't seem to have the thelepathic abilities Sylveon displayed. Once she earned her second heart, she immediately started earning boosted EXP. She also starting dancing at the beginning of battle as Greninja had.

Earning two hearts of Affection in Pokémon-Amie will boost EXP earned for the beloved pokémon

Comment: Here is a source confirming that you can get EXP boosts as well as otehr effects http://www.serebii.net/xy/pokemonamie.shtml

Answer (score 5):

Boosted EXP without being traded may be a result of the EXP Point O-Power, which somebody might have buffed you with. If you were connected to the Internet through the Player Search  System (PSS), this is the most likely case. To get this O-Power yourself, you must talk to Mr. Bonding in the Anistar Pokemon Center.

Also, it seems that increasing your Pokemon's affection and related stats through Pokemon-Amie has a chance to increase EXP gained along with a host of other effects.

Comment: He's the only one getting boosted EXP, though (Well, him and the traded Torchic) Is that how the O-Power works?

Comment: I believe the O-Power selects a single Pokemon for boosted EXP. Not quite sure how as I haven't gotten that buff very often so I can't test it.

Comment: That sounds plausible, though like you I can't quite test it yet. Also, it has been going on for a really long time (I first noticed it late last night and it's still going)

Comment: Yeah, I think affection is the likely cause, here.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Me too. I'm waiting for the ban on accepting my own answer to expire to accept my research

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional way to get boosted EXP that has yet to be mentioned (though it obviously doesn't apply to your situation here).

Aside from trade (which you already mentioned), Pokemon will get boosted EXP if you **stop a level-based evolution from evolving**.

My Weedle, Steve, is now level 8 and gets boosted EXP for every battle we're in. Were I to let him evolve into Kakuna (this naturally happens at 7), this boost would stop.

Comment: Greninja is a fully evolved pokemon so that is not the case here.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot RavenDreamer actually mentioned that in the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I caught a Gible in the wastelands, and I've never battled with it (not even had it in my party) until today, and in my first battle, it gained boosted exp. I've never super trained with it, nor have I played with it on Pokemon-Amie. I have no idea what is going on with it. But it would seem that other Pokemon do get boosted exp when played with and their affection goes up.

In all honesty, this could be a glitch from the game itself. Infecting random Pokemon. Because none of my other Pokemon are exhibiting this symptom. I'm thinking about contacting Game Freak or something b/c I don't want my progress erased. You never really know..

Also, I've done PA (Amie) up to two hearts, and that Pokemon never gained boosted exp. I'm gonna try and do more research on this.

Comment: Check whether it's really yours (OT+ID), maybe you mistook it for one you got in a Wonder Trade or something. Also check for Pokerus, Lucky Egg, and Amie stats. Maybe something raised those stats which you don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

My Pikachu gained a similar boost in Exp gains. I noticed she had a strange purple dot on her head in the Pokemon-Amie tab, and went to play with her to see what it was. The dot was gone, but she looked a little sick at first, but that went away when I fed, pet, and played with her.

When I sent her out into battle, she swayed side to side, and the game said, "Harley [my pikachu] looks a little out of it." and from that point on, she's been gaining bonus Exp.

Answer (score 0):

Yea I believe that maxing out a pokemons evs causes an exp boost. I was teambuilding and I noticed that after I ev trained my freshly bred team, the exp boost happened. Amie also causes this with a certain amount of affection, but pokerus does not affect it, as that doubles ev gain and not exp gain.

Answer (score -1):

Your Pokemon may have the ability [Anticipation](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Anticipation_(Ability))

Anticipation causes the Pokemon to shudder when you're in battle with an opponent who has a super effective move or a one hit KO move. Depending on what the rules for it are in Gen 6, it may also trigger when a Pokemon has Self Destruct or Explosion (this varies between previous versions)

It will not notify the Pokemon in the case of a super-effective Hidden Power, Judgment, Weather Ball, or Natural Gift, as they are normally Normal-type. Counter, Metal Burst, and Mirror Coat are also not detected.

Comment: He (Water/Dark) just shuddered at the beginning of a battle against a Tentacool with Acid (Poison), Toxic Spike (Poison), Bubble Beam (Water) and Wrap (Normal). Unless I'm doing my Type arithmetics wrong, none of those is super effective or a one-hit KO

Comment: Well, I've seen a Pokémon actually use Anticipation and this is not it. Anticipation shows the label and text says the pokémon is shuddering. This is actual movement on screen. On the other hand, you'll notice I changed the main question; the movement is intriguing, but I'm really more interested in the EXP increase. I just thought they were linked at first.

Comment: The Froakie line has Torrent, same as any water starters.

Answer (score -1):

My Absol has been gaining a boost as well, but I haven't been on Pokemon-Amie with her at all recently. But I did get all the medals on Super Training with her. So I'm thinking that's why she's been getting a boost in experience points after winning battles or catching Pokemon.
So that could also be why Greninja is gaining boosted experience points. :)