# Do XP boosting items affect Exp. Share when calculated?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

There are a few things which increase XP gain at the end of a battle, for example:

- A traded Pokemon gains more XP naturally
- The *[Lucky Egg](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Lucky_Egg)* held item
- The Exp. Point O-Power
- [Pokemon Amie Affection](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135398/why-does-my-greninja-get-boosted-exp)

I know that Exp. Share gives half of the earned XP to the other Pokemon in the party. But do these XP increases affect the halved XP total when using Exp. Share?

I'm specifically asking about the active or 'battling' Pokémon. If this Pokémon is holding the Lucky Egg, or has maxed out Affection etc, does the boost get applied to all other Pokemon in the party?

Comment: This question has already been answered here. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135543/does-lucky-egg-boost-the-experience-gain-from-exp-share?rq=1

Comment: @AdamP - its related yes, but not a duplicate. I'm specifically asking whether the boosts applied to the active Pokémon are calculated for the party as well. That question asks whether another Pokémon in the party receives a bonus if they are holding the Lucky Egg

Comment: and if you look at the accepted answer it has that information. It uses the same numbers I do.

Comment: @AdamP - and we don't mark dupes based on an answer containing the answer for another related question. Besides, the answer you've provided on both only stands for Lucky Egg, what about the other XP-boosts?

Comment: I do not know if all exp boosts are 50% but all boosts will behave as describe below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Effects that boost exp gain will not boost the entire parties exp gain when the pokemon in question participated in battle. You will see the active pokemon get boosted exp and then the rest of your pokemon get half of "normal" exp.

- For example if you had a pokemon with a lucky egg up front and he got
  150 exp then the rest of your pokemon would get 50 (half of 100, the
  original exp gain).

However, as Haidro points out, if the pokemon that would get boosted exp does not participate in battle they will still get boosted exp of the half they receive from the exp share.

- So if you had a pokemon up front with no boosted exp and they got 100. Most of your pokemon would get 50 but the one with the exp boost would get 75 (50 boosted).

Note these numbers assume 50% exp boost, I'm not positive that is correct but its easy to do math with and I feel it still shows the point.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for the Lucky Egg, and yes, that boosts the Exp. Share.

While training some level 1 pokemon with Exp. Share, I put a lucky egg on my level 1 abra. All the level 1 pokemon levelled the same rate except abra, which was always ahead.

So yes, the lucky egg boosts. I wouldn't see why the others would not "stack".

Comment: Was abra the active pokemon though? I'm mainly interested from boosts applied from the active (battling) Pokémon

Comment: @Robotnik Nope, he was not.